# org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer#doSend throws OOM error | KafkaTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, out-of-memory, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am using KafkaTemplate to produce message to a topic but getting OOM Error while KafkaProducer calls doSend(). Not sure it's related.
Pod is given 2Gi of memory and we are processing around 10K messages in a batch of 200.

Below code is where it all goes wrong.

```
final ProducerRecord<String, byte[]> record =
    new ProducerRecord(message.getTopicIdentifier(), message.getKey(), message.getData());

message.getMetaData().getKeyValueMap().forEach((key, value) -> record.headers().add(key, value.getBytes()));
ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, byte[]>> listenableFuture =  kafkaTemplate.send(record);
listenableFuture.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<>() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, byte[]> result) {
        log.debug("Message : {} published to Kafka successful", message.getId());
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
        log.error("[onFailure] Error processing message: {}", message.getId(), ex);
    }
});
```

MessageDTO and other related class is like

```
public class Metadata {

    private Map<String,String> keyValueMap;
}

public class MessageDTO {

    private Long id;
    private byte[] data;
    private String key;
    private String status;
    private String reason;
    private String topicIdentifier;
    private Date createdDate;
    private Date updateDate;
    private Metadata metaData;
}
```

Below is the producer config and resources allowed to the pod

```
spring:
    kafka:
      producer:
        bootstrapServers: **server**
        acks: all
        compressionType: lz4
        retries: 5

  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 1000m
      memory: 2048Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 4m
      memory: 128Mi
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not nearly enough information; what is the message size, etc, etc,; you need to figure out what's consuming the memory, e.g. with a heap dump - by default, the producer(s) will block when 32Mb is pending sends https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_buffer.memory so this should normally not be a problem.

Comment: Just because the pod has 2Gi memory, your actual container JVM may not care about this. For example, `-Xmx` has been hard-coded limit

Answer (score 0):

You’re using 200 record batches. You can try reducing the batch size to 10 or even 1 and check if it stops throwing OOM - then increase it gradually while watching the memory metrics to find the right batch size for one application instance. Then you can scale up or scale out.

Also check if the VM is properly configured and using the available memory - that might allow for a bigger batch size per application instance.